# How to write the output of my programme to a file or list

Tags: python, file-io

I have a program on my machine which runs in my terminal window, and returns lists of info. For example:

```
t000930_152536.SFTC   1369.000
t031109_124140.SFTC   1369.000
t140207_071131.SFTC   3094.000
t190222_011122.SFTC   1369.000
t100423_011232.SFTC   1369.000
t190423_021543.SFTC   1369.000
t190714_205113.SFTC   3094.000
t110115_085319.SFTC   3094.000
```

All I want to do is to grab this info with Python - whether that be to write it into a file, or make it a list..

Here was my naive attempt:

```
#!usr/bin/python
import os

os.chdir('./P574/J0998-1034')

f = open('1400list.txt','w')
os.system('vap -c freq *.SFTC') # this tells my other programme to create its list
f.close
```

But the file created remains empty. Would love some help on this simple issue please!

Comment: Incidentally, you can use this sort of redirection at the terminal directly. You only really need python involved if you want to take the output and manipulate it in some way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try normal file redirection.
Assuming, vap prints its information on stdout, this approach should work for you:

```
#!usr/bin/python
import os

os.chdir('./P574/J0998-1034')
os.system('vap -c freq *.SFTC > 1400list.txt')
```